# Spring-Boot MQTT Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, mqtt, paho

I have a requirement to send payload to a lot of devices whose names are picked from Database. Then, i have to send to different topics, which will be like `settings/{put devicename here}`.

Below is the configuration i was using which i got from spring-boot reference documents.

**MQTTConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class MQTTConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Settings settings;
@Autowired
private DevMqttMessageListener messageListener;

@Bean
MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory clientFactory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    clientFactory.setServerURIs(settings.getMqttBrokerUrl());
    clientFactory.setUserName(settings.getMqttBrokerUser());
    clientFactory.setPassword(settings.getMqttBrokerPassword());
    return clientFactory;
}

@Bean
MessageChannel mqttOutboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
public MessageHandler mqttOutbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageHandler messageHandler = new MqttPahoMessageHandler("dev-client-outbound",
            mqttClientFactory());
    messageHandler.setAsync(true);
    messageHandler.setDefaultTopic(settings.getMqttPublishTopic());
    return messageHandler;
}

@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutboundChannel")
public interface DeviceGateway {
    void sendToMqtt(String payload);
}
}
```

Here, i am sending to only 1 topic. So i added the bean like below to send to multiple number of topics;

```
@Bean
public MqttClient mqttClient() throws MqttException {
    MqttClient mqttClient = new MqttClient(settings.getMqttBrokerUrl(), "dev-client-outbound");
    MqttConnectOptions connOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    connOptions.setUserName(settings.getMqttBrokerUser());
    connOptions.setPassword(settings.getMqttBrokerPassword().toCharArray());
    mqttClient.connect(connOptions);
    return mqttClient;
}
```

and i send using,

```
try {       
    mqttClient.publish(settings.getMqttPublishTopic()+device.getName(), mqttMessage);
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error While Sending Mqtt Messages", e);
    }
```

Which works.

But my question is, **Can i achieve the same, using output channel for better performance? If yes, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MqttClient` is synchronous.

The `MqttPahoMessageHandler` uses an `MqttAsyncClient` and can be configured (set `async` to `true`) to not wait for the confirmation, but publish the confirmation later as an application event.

If you are using your own code and sending multiple messages in a loop, it will probably be faster to use an async client, and wait for the `IMqttDeliveryToken` completions later.

Comment: can the `MqttPahoMessageHandler` configured to send to whatever topic i like? Here i am restrcted to 1 topic `messageHandler.setDefaultTopic(settings.getMqttPublishTopic());`. Can i remove this restriction and have a method like `void sendToMqtt(String topicName, String payload);` ? Where i specify the topic name each time i send a message.

Comment: As stated in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html#CO39-7), that's a __default__ topic; it's only used if the message doesn't contain an `mqtt_topic` header (constant `MqttHeaders.TOPIC`). You can add the header in several ways - for example, with a header enricher, a `@GatewayHeader` with an expression on the `@Gateway` method or in the gateway method itself: `void sendToMqtt(String payload, @Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC) String topic);`.

Comment: @GaryRussell is that possible to use multiple topic with sendToMqtt, if it is can you explain?

Comment: You need to ask a new question if it's different to this one. Extended dialogs in comments are not allowed here.